# c# HttpClient.PostAsync only works once

Tags: c#, .net, post, upload, httpclient

I'm working on a windows client for uploading a lot of small files over an http post request.
I’m using .NET 4.5.2

```
public async void Upload3(HttpClient client, string url, string[] files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);
            HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                content.Add(fileStreamContent);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                //code is stopping at the following line:
                string finalresults = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(finalresults);
                Console.WriteLine(" > Uploaded file " + info.Name);
            }
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("> Uploaded all files");
}
```

The Code is working fine for the very first file. But every other file is not uploaded. When I try to debug the code step by step, the code execution stops (in the second iteration of the loop) on this line:

```
string finalresults = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Since the server log only shows on single request, I think that the error already occurs in this line:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Even if I use different HttpClient objects and different FileStream objects, the upload is only working for the first file.
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: How are you calling this function? Are you `await`ing it properly all the way up the chain?

Comment: Yes. The problem is not that it is shutdown before it has finished. 
It just stops at "await response..." and after a few minutes it throws a generic exception.

Answer (score 0):

For your requiment, you can user third party libraries like RESTSharp. There are lots of examples and good documentation. Also it is easy to use.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that in the meantime.
But I really want to understand why this is not working. So I'm still searching  for a suitable explenation.